# Load HTML file stored on Google Drive in a WebView

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-webview

I have some HTML files stored on `Google Drive`. The file have Public Sharing Access.I have `WebView` in application `Fragment`. I have enabled `Javascript` settings also for Webview. But when the link is opened in WebView the Text HTML file get opened. How to load that HTML file as a normal HTML page ?
This is a code for WebView where that Google Drive link is opened.

```
if(getArguments()!=null){
            web.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/abcabcabcabc/view?usp=sharing");
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        }
```

Comment: Your url is wrong, there is no file name, also not ending the url with html extension.

Comment: Did you solve this?